# Oracle Query Taking Time

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, sql-tuning

I am running this oracle query , But its taking lot of time, I have also tried indexing, but still taking lot of time. 
Can the below Query can be tuned or can be write in other way to execute fast.

```
select * 
from table1  
where (col_1 like '8%' OR col_1 like '9%') 
    and col_1 not in (select col_11 
                        from table2 
                        where id =2 
                            and (col_11 like '9%' OR col_11 like '8%'))
```

Comment: Please run an explain plan and post the results.

Answer (score 2):

This is slow

```
where field not in (subquery)
```

This is less intuitive, but faster

```
where field in (select all the values
minus
select the values you don't want)
```

Other variations include

```
where not exists(subquery)
```

or

```
from table1 left join table2 on table1.field = table2.field
where table2.field is null
```

Comment: `in` and `not in` are slow in oracle. Your second example with `join` should work better

Comment: can u please give the query with conditions, mine is getting error

Comment: This is not a spoon feeding site.  You have to sort out your own errors, just like I have to sort out mine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where (col_1 like '8%' or col_1 like '9%') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.col_11 = t1.col1 and t2.id = 2
                 );
```

The condition in the subquery on `(t2.col_11 like '9%' OR t2.col_11 like '8%')` is already handled by `t2.col_11 = t1.col1` and the outer condition.

Then for this query, you want an index on `table2(col_11, id)`.

You can try an index on `table1(col_1)`.  However, this is probably not selective enough to improve query performance.